# Execute the base class method and its overridden version by the child class object

Tags: python, oop, overriding

Is it possible?
I have base class A...something like this for example:

```
 class A:
 def calc(self):
    a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
    b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
    c=a+b
    return(c)
```

And inherited class:

```
class B(A):
def calc(self):
    x=random.randint(10,100)
    lst=[random.randint(5,35) for i in range(x)]
    print(lst)
```

My main task is "Create an object of class B and call the base and overridden calc() method.".
But I can't understand how I can do it.

```
    obj=B()
    obj.calc()
```

It execute only overriden method, how I can execute base method too?

Comment: This sounds like a terrible assignment. Why is `calc` an instance method when it doesn't use `self` at all? Why is `B` a subclass of `A`, let alone a class at all?

Comment: *Where* are you supposed to call the base class's method? From `obj`, or from inside `B.calc`?

Comment: what you need is the `super()` method. See [this](https://www.askpython.com/python/built-in-methods/super-method-in-python) for example

Comment: @chepner from obj. I totally agree with you, this assignment is terrible. 
I couldn't find a solution on the internet, so I decided to ask here. And judging by your reaction, I understand the teacher wrote the assignment incorrectly.

Comment: @chepner about " Why is calc an instance method when it doesn't use self at all? Why is B a subclass of A, let alone a class at all?".  Our class started learning OOP, and our teacher gives us tasks like this. But honestly, I don't get the idea why we create method that don't use self variables.
And thanks for you answer and help <3

Comment: Just be aware that these are *horrible* examples of OOP. Just because class syntax is being used doesn't mean you are being shown good examples of how classes should be used.